# How can I extend a TypeScript class that implements an interface, and leave some implementations to the parent class?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Sorry for the long winded title. I'm using ngBootstrap and UIRouter, and I'm trying to create a subclass of `Ng2StateDeclaration` that opens and closes a `ngbModal` as it enters and exits. I can do this easily without inheritance but I'm after a neater solution.

Heres what I've got:

```
var modalInstance:NgbModalRef;
class ModalStateDeclaration implements Ng2StateDeclaration {
    name:string;
    url:string;
    onEnter(transition: Transition, state: Ng2StateDeclaration) {
        modalInstance = modalService.open(SomeComponent);

        for (var key in transition.params()) {
            modalInstance.componentInstance[key] = transition.params()[key];
        }

        var currentState = transition.from().name;
        modalInstance.result.catch(function(reason) {
            if (currentState) {
                window.history.back();
            } else {
                stateService.go('home');
            }
        });
    }

    onExit() {
        modalInstance.close();
    }
}

export const modalBookState:ModalStateDeclaration = {
    name: 'modalBookState',
    url: '/b/:id'
};
```

TypeScript is telling me that `modalBookState` is missing `onEnter` and `onExit`. How can I use the `onEnter` and `onExit` implementations from `ModalStateDeclaration`? Do I need to implement them with `super()`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just new up the class not assign an object literal to it, and add a constructor to the class

```
class ModalStateDeclaration implements Ng2StateDeclaration {
    constructor(public name:string, public url:string) {} 
    ...
}
// The type annotation is optional you could remove :ModalStateDeclaration, I left it in for clarity
export const modalBookState:ModalStateDeclaration = new ModalStateDeclaration('modalBookState', '/b/:id');
```

If you really want to create an object literal instead of instantiating your class you could do something like this:

```
export const modalBookState:ModalStateDeclaration = {
    onEnter: ModalStateDeclaration.prototype.onEnter,
    onExit: ModalStateDeclaration.prototype.onExit,
    name: 'modalBookState',
    url: '/b/:id'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against using an object literal directly, or anything but a `new ModalStateDelcaration(...)` since it will fail `instanceof` checks at runtime.

I would do something like this:

```
const modalBookStateOptions: Partial<ModalStateDeclaration> = {
  name: 'modalBookState',
  url: '/b/:id'
}
```

The type `Partial<ModalStateDeclaration>` means `modalBookStateOptions` has *some* of the properties of `ModalStateDeclaration`.  (`Partial<T>` is mentioned in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) if you want to read more).

Then, you can create your actual `ModalStateDeclaration` by merging the partial object into a new instance of the class:

```
export const modalBookState: ModalStateDeclaration = Object.assign(new ModalStateDeclaration, modalBookStateOptions);
```

There are other ways to do this (@Titian gave some other options) but this is how I'd go about it.

Good luck!